# How to test the page loading time with Gatling

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

For example- I need to check that for 1000 users it responds in 3 seconds.

Is the number of users and response times configurable?

Answer (score 6):

**This answer targets Gatling 2.**

You can set the target number of users by configuring the "injection profile" of your simulation:

```
setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1000)) // To start all users at the same time
setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(1000) over (30 seconds) // To start gradually, over 30 seconds
```

For more information, please refer to [the injection DSL documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/general/simulation_setup.html#injection)

If you want to check that all your users responds in less than 3 seconds, one way to ensure this is [Gatling's assertions](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/general/assertions.html):

```
setUp(...).assertions(global.responseTime.max.lessThan(3000))
```

If this assertion fails, meaning at least one user responded in more than 3 seconds, Gatling will clearly indicate the failure after your simulation is completed.